# Ionic 4 wildcard routing for paths separated by slash

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

The question is based on an Ionic 4 project with Angular:

If a route does not exist in the app-routing.module, it should be redirected to 'home'.

Therefore the last route: `{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }` was added. 
If you now access 'http://localhost:8100/test', the route will be redirected to 'home', like expected.

However, if I access 'http://localhost:8100/test/test', I end up on an empty page. Why doesn't the statement also apply to the second path, separated by slash ?

Comment: is this similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36260839/angular-2-how-to-redirect-to-404-or-other-path-if-the-path-does-not-exist ?

Comment: The solution given there is the one I am already using. Forwarding also works for any paths, as long as they are not separated by slash which is the case here. But my goal is to forward every route if it doesn't exist. At no time should the user end up on an empty page.

Comment: could you provide a stackblitz code ?

Comment: While trying it out, I happened to be able to solve it.
I changed `<base href="/" />` in index.html to `<base href="./" />`. 
The reason for this change was that the Ionic 4 app under Windows only displays a white page if I don't do this. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52742354/ionic-v4-windows-platform-giving-blank-screen

If I undo this change, everything will work as expected. This would solve the original problem for all other platforms but of course the app is not usable under Windows.